# This App cannot open

Tags: windows-8, screen-resolution

I installed trail version of windows 8 in inspiron Dell mini 10 in this I open app it shows

> This app cannot open the screen resolution is too low for this app to
>   run

my screen resolution is 1024*600 error message shows

> your resolution is lower than 1024*768 sometimes items might not fit
>   and apps might not open

help me for how to open the app and adjust setting in windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the next instrucctions:**

1. Press "WIN+R" key combination to launch RUN dialog box then type regedit and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
2. Now press "Ctrl+F" keys and it'll open Find dialog box. You can also open it using "Edit -> Find" menu.
   Now type following text in Find text box:

**Display1_DownScalingSupported**

1. Click on "Find Next" button and it'll let you go to the first occurrence of the above mentioned registry key. Once you find a key with the name "Display1_DownScalingSupported", change its value from 0 to 1
2. Press F3 key and it'll let you go to the next occurrence of the text string. If you find more keys with the name "Display1_DownScalingSupported", change values of all of them from 0 to 1
3. Once finished, close Registry Editor and restart your system.
4. After reboot, right-click on Desktop and select "Screen Resolution" option. Now you should get 1024x768 option in the screen resolution list. Select it and apply the changes.
5. That's it. This trick will force Windows to think that your screen resolution is 1024x768 and you'll be able to run metro apps without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum resolution to run Windows Store (formerly "Metro-style") apps is 1024x768.  This doesn't apply to all of your desktop apps.  Here is a [reference to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780612.aspx#minimum_screen_resolutions) on this.